# Selección de campo en un array bajo un condicional: Como capturar los datos que acompañan a dicho campo en variables?

Tags: php, array

Estimados solicito su colaboración con algo de luz sobre este tema que me tiene bastante líado ya :).

Tengo un array de datos que proviene de unas consultas a la base de datos. El array puede tener desde un registro hasta 12 como máximo. En el ejemplo tenemos un array de 6 obligaciones, el campo 'tm' representa las tasas mensuales y basado en este se deben seleccionar las tasas mayores o iguales, luego, basado en ello, tomar los valores de las obligaciones ('vr') que acompañan y los números de obligación ('numob') para crear un nuevo array con esa información depurada o bien capturarlo en variables para someterlo a otro proceso. A continuación remito el ejemplo hasta donde voy esperando que algún gurú se apiade. Gracias de antemano.

```
<?php
$t_objetivo = 1.3;
echo "La tasa objetivo es: " . $t_objetivo;
// Las siguientes variables originalmente provienen de una consulta a la BBDD y pueden variar desde 1 hasta 12 registros.
// tm representa las tasas porcentuales para las distintas obligaciones.
$tm1 = 1.0;
$tm2 = 1.5;
$tm3 = 1.3;
$tm4 = 1.2;
$tm5 = 1.7;
$tm6 = 1.7;
// vr representa los valores de las obligaciones.
$vr1 = 35000;
$vr2 = 50000;
$vr3 = 180000;
$vr4 = 18000;
$vr5 = 73000;
$vr6 = 110000;
// numob representa el codigo de la obligación que es unico e irrepetible.
$numob1 = 12555;
$numob2 = 13584;
$numob3 = 14876;
$numob4 = 55684;
$numob5 = 38742;
$numob6 = 42589;
//'lp' representa la descripción de la obligación.
$lp1 = 'Libre Inversión';
$lp2 = 'Libre Inversión 2';
$lp3 = 'Libre Inversión 3';
$lp4 = 'Libre Inversión 4';
$lp5 = 'Libre Inversión 5';
$lp6 = 'Libre Inversión 6';
// Para efectos del ejemplo se ha creado el array acorde a las variables dadas.
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm1,
    'vr' => $vr1,
    'numob' => $numob1,
    'lp' => $lp1
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm2,
    'vr' => $vr2,
    'numob' => $numob2,
    'lp' => $lp2
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm3,
    'vr' => $vr3,
    'numob' => $numob3,
    'lp' => $lp3
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm4,
    'vr' => $vr4,
    'numob' => $numob4,
    'lp' => $lp4
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm5,
    'vr' => $vr5,
    'numob' => $numob5,
    'lp' => $lp5
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm6,
    'vr' => $vr6,
    'numob' => $numob6,
    'lp' => $lp6
);

// Objetivo:Recorrer el array buscando obtener las tasas mensuales ('tm') superiores o iguales para que posteriormente se puedan tomar los datos de valores ('vr') que las acompañan para someterlas a otro proceso.
foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
        if (($k === 'tm') && ($v >= $t_objetivo)) {
            var_dump($k, $v);               
           // PREGUNTA: Como poder obtener el valor ('vr') y numero de obligación('numob') de cada obligación que cumple con la condición de la linea 23?
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Quizá esto se puede simplificar, pero no entiendo muy bien lo que tiene que ocurrir cuando `$v >= $t_objetivo` ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No necesitas loops anidados, puedes accesar a las propiedades con un solo `foreach` asi:

```
<?php
$t_objetivo = 1.3;
echo "La tasa objetivo es: " . $t_objetivo;
// Las siguientes variables originalmente provienen de una consulta a la BBDD y pueden variar desde 1 hasta 12 registros.
// tm representa las tasas porcentuales para las distintas obligaciones.
$tm1 = 1.0;
$tm2 = 1.5;
$tm3 = 1.3;
$tm4 = 1.2;
$tm5 = 1.7;
$tm6 = 1.7;
// vr representa los valores de las obligaciones.
$vr1 = 35000;
$vr2 = 50000;
$vr3 = 180000;
$vr4 = 18000;
$vr5 = 73000;
$vr6 = 110000;
// numob representa el codigo de la obligación que es unico e irrepetible.
$numob1 = 12555;
$numob2 = 13584;
$numob3 = 14876;
$numob4 = 55684;
$numob5 = 38742;
$numob6 = 42589;
//'lp' representa la descripción de la obligación.
$lp1 = 'Libre Inversión';
$lp2 = 'Libre Inversión 2';
$lp3 = 'Libre Inversión 3';
$lp4 = 'Libre Inversión 4';
$lp5 = 'Libre Inversión 5';
$lp6 = 'Libre Inversión 6';
// Para efectos del ejemplo se ha creado el array acorde a las variables dadas.
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm1,
    'vr' => $vr1,
    'numob' => $numob1,
    'lp' => $lp1
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm2,
    'vr' => $vr2,
    'numob' => $numob2,
    'lp' => $lp2
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm3,
    'vr' => $vr3,
    'numob' => $numob3,
    'lp' => $lp3
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm4,
    'vr' => $vr4,
    'numob' => $numob4,
    'lp' => $lp4
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm5,
    'vr' => $vr5,
    'numob' => $numob5,
    'lp' => $lp5
);
$datos[] = array(
    'tm' => $tm6,
    'vr' => $vr6,
    'numob' => $numob6,
    'lp' => $lp6
);
echo '<br>';
// Objetivo:Recorrer el array buscando obtener las tasas mensuales ('tm') superiores o iguales para que posteriormente se puedan tomar los datos de valores ('vr') que las acompañan para someterlas a otro proceso.
foreach ($datos as $key => $value) {    
        if (($value['tm'] >= $t_objetivo)) {
            echo $value['tm'] . " " . $value['vr'] . " " . $value['numob'];    
            echo '<br>';
           // PREGUNTA: Como poder obtener el valor ('vr') y numero de obligación('numob') de cada obligación que cumple con la condición de la linea 23?
        }

}
?>
```